# Can't write cookie on Tablet running Android 3.1?

Tags: android, cordova, tablet

Not sure if anyone can help me on this; but let me throw it out
there.  I'm really not sure if this is a Phonegap issue, a device
issue or an Android SDK version.  Tell me what you think..

I have an Android Applet using phonegap version 0.9.5; Android SDK
3.0.  One of the features is after login; I write a cookie using
javascript on the device to store the email entered.  This works in
many of the phones I have tested on  and also tested on all the
emulators.

The problem is I have an Acer A500 tablet running version 3.1.  Every
time I login; I can not write the cookie to the tablet.  It appears
that I get the length of the cookie; always 0.  But can't write a
cookie or read a cookie

So; any ideas if this is a Phonegap issue, a Acer table issue or a
Android sdk issue? Suggestions?

The javascript to write/read the cookie is pretty standard:

----Write Cookie---
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + 1095);

```
document.cookie = "email=" + escape(oForm.elements['email'].value) +
```

### ";expires=" + exdate.toUTCString();

--Read Cookie----
    function readCookie(cookieName)
    {
            var cookieValue = null;

```
        if (document.cookie.length>0)
  {
 c_start=document.cookie.indexOf(cookieName + "=");
  if (c_start!=-1)
    {
    c_start=c_start + cookieName.length+1;
    c_end=document.cookie.indexOf(";",c_start);
    if (c_end==-1) c_end=document.cookie.length;
    return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start,c_end));
    }
  }
return cookieValue;

}
```

When I read the cookie..email always returns null and the length of
the cookie is 0.

Thanks for any advice or suggestions...
Tony

Answer (score 3):

It's a bug with Android 3.1. I tested the exact same code with 2.3.4 (sdk version 10) and it works as expected. The 3.1 was on a Galaxy Tab and the 2.3.4 was on a Nexus S.